# Passing ? in ReWrite Rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite

I am using this -

RewriteRule ^/one/([a-zA-Z-]+)/(two|TWO)/(three|THREE)/([a-zA-Z0-9()-.\?\=]*)/?$ /city/city-search.php?c=$1&t=$2&pf=$3&iptnr=$4

I am caling - www.winsoftwares.net/one/pune/two/three/index.php?ptnr=xyz
and want to access variables in city-search.php like ... one , pune, two, three and ptnr value

but as string find '?' in (index.php?ptnr=xyz) it breaking....please help me

http://www.winsoftwares.net is not able to redirect this...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to examine the entire URL including parameters in one hit. You need to examine anything after the ? separately with a QUERY_STRING, eg.
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=blah(.*) [NC]`

Comment: i use it its work for me but my parameter is not mandatory.... so what should i do..i use 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ptnr=(.*)$

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, to rewrite anything with a pntr parameter first (note that this will match more than one parameter but only if ptnr is first) then use this RewriteCond then have a RewriteRule underneath

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `?` since it's a special character in regular expressions.

So instead of using `?` try `\?`

Comment: please check the above rewrite rule....already escaped

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't include the QUERY STRING in your matching pattern.
Then you just add %{QUERY_STRING} to your rewrite rule.
Example:

```
RewriteRule  ^/(articles)/([-a-z]+)-([0-9]+)/$  /index.php?cat=$1&id=$3&rewrite=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

The [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) writes:

> Note: Query String
>
> The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a RewriteCond with the %{QUERY_STRING} variable.

Comment: thanks a lot dear..http://www.winsoftwares.net got started to respond now...its really great help today

Comment: No problem.. just vote me up if I helped you ;)